# Indentation with cdlatex

Tags: auctex

I am using Emacs 25.1.1 on Windows 10 OS with *AUCTeX* and the *CDLaTeX* minor mode.

CDLaTeX has a very useful feature of command input, which is typing a shortcut followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> to expand that shortcut. For instance, when I type `eqt` <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will input a whole LaTeX equation environment and move the cursor into this environment.

**My question:**

Regarding the indentation of this environment input: It just doesn't respect the current indentation (like child, subchild, etc). I search around and there seems no information about this.

Is there any *hot fix* for this general environment input indentation thing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `cdlatex` mode, it doesn't appear to be designed with modifying the inserted templates in mind (I could be wrong).

The [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) package does offer completely customizable templates, with the option to have them respect indentation. It takes a bit of reading to figure it out, but once you do you can write your own templates to do fairly complex insertions. For your example, the following:

```
# name: eqt
# key: eqt
# --
\begin{equation}
$> $0
\end{equation}
```

Will create a snippet, bound to the text `eqt`, that expands to an equation environment, and the environment will be indented as appropriate based on the surrounding environments (if any).

If that looks interesting, check the documentation for `yasnippet`. You need to install the package (via `package-list-packages`), enable the mode for latex files, and write or install the snippets you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can define new environments in cdlatex using `cdlatex-env-alist` and assign a hotkey to those with `cdlatex-command-alist`.

For your case,

```lisp
(setq cdlatex-env-alist '(("equation" "\\begin{equation}\n\t ?  AUTOLABEL \n\\end{equation}" nil)))
```

This will override the default `equation` environment. Note that `\t` inserts the tab just before the cursor. Checkout the [documentation](https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex) for more details.

Comment: I thought this didn't work on my system, and it took me a while to figure out that by default, you cannot insert the cdlatex environments with `C-c C-e`, but need `M-x cdlatex-environment` or `C-c{`.